# How to submit data in a custom form in wordpress and then from that submitted data how to fetch specific details from database and show to user?

Tags: database, wordpress

```
  My Form Looks Like this
 <form action="" method="post">

 <input type="text" name="isbn" placeholder="Enter 10/13 Digit ISBN Number To Sell Your Book"/>
 <input type="submit" name="Search Isbn">
 </form>
 // now i am new to php and html so i dont know what to wrote in form action tag.. 
 I have a table in my wordpress database with a name "booksisbn" in which i have 3 fields which are book title, book isbn and book image.... Data in all these fields are manually inserted by me..
```

So i want from this form that when someone enter 13 digit book's isbn number and submitted then that number should be match from my "booksisbn" table's isbn field.. and if user's entered isbn matches from my table then all 3 fields like title, book isbn and book image should be shown to that user.

Please can anyone help me to do this.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you have to first create a custom post type for books and have to add custom fields like title, booksisbn, image etc so admin can add them to database from wp-admin and have to put the filter functionality to some of your page template (create page template).

1. Create Custom post type : https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-post-types-in-wordpress/
2. Create custom field through acf plugin https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/
3. Create template in wordpress : https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/
4. Retrieve custom post information to your template : https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-another-post/

Comment: if you don't mine is there any other way by using php script.????

Comment: Yes create a code in functions.php file and create a shortcode or create a template with php code. But i suggest you to follow that standard wordpress coding. If you need i can help you when you find yourself into trouble.

Comment: i have create a custom post type by that plugin and also created 3 custom fields with the help of acf plugin. but now i am blank. so please guide me what to do after this.. and what is the need of creating template?

Comment: sir please send your email so that i can explain you more easily what i am facing

Comment: ravisinghit@gmail.com please share the details of database, and your sample code so i will help you when i get time.

Comment: sir i have emailed you there.. please check... and please help me as soon as possible.